# What‘s the difference between the checkbox and the yes option in the trust the authors dialog box?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As mentioned in the title, you can see "Trust the authors of all files in the parent folder" checkbox and "Yes, I trust the authors" button in the picture. I don't know the difference of them. When should I check this checkbox?

[image: dialog box]

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest sense, the difference is you can choose to trust *only* the current folder (leave the checkbox unchecked), or you can choose to trust all folders and files found in the parent folder "Microcontrollers" (check the checkbox).

From [Visual Studio Codes Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust#_selecting-a-parent-folder):

> When you trust a folder via the Workspace Trust editor, you have the option to trust the parent folder. This will apply trust to the parent folder and all subfolders.
>
> This can be helpful if you have many folders with trusted content co-located under one folder.
>
> When opening a subfolder under a trusted parent, you won't see the usual Don't Trust button to put you back in Restricted Mode, instead there is text mentioning that your folder is trusted due to another folder.

To help understand this, they also include a small example.

```
├── TrustedRepos - Clone trusted repositories under this parent folder
└── ForEvaluation - Clone experimental or unfamiliar repositories under this parent folder
```

Along with this example, they state:

> For example, you could put all trusted repos under a "TrustedRepos" parent folder, and unfamiliar repos under another parent folder such as "ForEvaluation". You would trust the "TrustedRepos" folder, and selectively trust folders under "ForEvaluation".